# MVC3 One model, One Controller, One (CRUD) View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have what i call "help tables" in my sql server database. These tables all contain the same attributes/fields. They will later be transformed into dropdowns. In my mvc3 application, i created a model, a view, and a controller for each table. I feel this is too much when it has to come to maintainability or extensibility.

My Q is: Is it possible to reduce the number of my MVC's by having only one of Each MVC for all my "help tables"? if it is... Can you please provide me with a small description or link or anything of the sort that would help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends upon your design you can have one controller for your entire project... are you using any ORM, enitity? NHibernate?, any pattern you are using in your project repository for example, if then you can have a single repository for the help tables and control them with one controller

here is a helpful link

[MVC repository pattern design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2449865/413670)