# In ASP.NET MVC repository pattern, does every class needs to have an interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm kind of confusing what should be a repository and what should have an interface.
Yes I know those are all for the comfort of unit tests.

Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository pattern helps you to make your application more manageable and scalable. It provides you facility to plug or unplug certain functionality with bare minimum changes and as well effecting application compatablity.

Generally when it comes to MVC Repository is used for Data Layer.

It is not neccessary to implement it but will be good if you do it and specific answer to your question it depends how you implement it as such one to one mapping of interface and class is not needed.

You can go through following link for more details

[MVC repository pattern design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449865/mvc-repository-pattern-design-decision)